# Any way to use Android tethering over USB for Kali Linux WiFi hacking?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, android, desktop

Okay, let's try and make this short enough. I have a desktop PC that I use myself, and I have Kali on a USB flash drive. I am a hobbyist penetration tester, and I'd like to know; is there any way that I could possibly use aircrack-ng or other WiFi exploitation tools over Android tethering through my USB cable?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how.  If your network connection so far as your desktop knows comes from the USB cable (as a network interface), `aircrack-ng` will probably see it as an ethernet (or other non-wireless) interface.

Comment: Well, I was thinking the same thing, but I'm curious, isn't there maybe any plugin that works over USB debugging or ADB to communicate with the phone's WiFi adapter? (though that'd be very complicated)

Comment: You'd be better served just rooting the phone and using `aircrack-ng` on the wireless interface directly (presuming the package is available or the source compilable for your Android hardware).

Comment: Sure you could try to hack together some way to pass the radio interface capabilities and command set over the USB to Kali so you can run the utilities from Kali machine instead of on the android device. You could also hack the Microsoft Hyper-V code to run the hypervisor under Wine on Linux...but it's an awful lot of work for a one off solution that already has better alternatives available. https://www.kali.org/kali-linux-nethunter/ and https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?31435-WiFi-adapter-for-Kali-Linux-on-a-Raspberry-Pi top the google list...